# Why is freeing pointers resulting in weird behavior and crashed?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, linked-list, free

I created linked lists in C and a few functions to help me with them.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int value;
    void *next;
} Node;

Node *NewNode(int value, Node *next) {
    Node *new = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    new->value = value;
    new->next = next;
    return new;
}


typedef struct {
    Node *head;
} List;

List NewList() {
    List lst = { .head = NULL };
    return lst;
}

void Erase(List *lst) {
    Node *current = lst->head;

    while (current != NULL) {
        Node *next = current->next;
        free(current);
        current = next;
    }

    lst->head = NULL;
}

void PrintList(List *lst) {
    Node *temp = lst->head;

    printf("[ ");

    while (temp != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", temp->value);
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    printf("]\n");

    free(temp);  // this works wtf?
}

void Push(List *lst, int val) {
    Node *new = NewNode(val, lst->head);
    lst->head = new;
}

void Pull(List *lst) {
    if (lst->head == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    Node *firstNode = lst->head;
    lst->head = lst->head->next;
    free(firstNode);
}


int GetAtIndex(List *lst, int index) {
    Node *temp = lst->head;

    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    int val = temp->value;

    return val;
}


int main() {
    List lst = NewList();

    Push(&lst, 6);
    Push(&lst, 7);
    Push(&lst, 8);
    Push(&lst, 9);
    PrintList(&lst);  // [ 9 8 7 6 ]

    PrintList(&lst);

    int index = 2;
    printf("lst[%d] = %d\n", index, GetAtIndex(&lst, index));

    PrintList(&lst);

    Erase(&lst);

    return 0;
}
```

I think I understand how pointers work to a "decent" level. What I'm still confused with is when to free them and how. In theory it should be simple... Free them when they aren't needed anymore. However I encountered a really strange issue when trying to follow that principle.

More precisely, I tried to add a `free(temp)` line to the `GetAtIndex` function, like this:

```c
int GetAtIndex(List *lst, int index) {
    Node *temp = lst->head;

    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    int val = temp->value;
    free(temp);  // over here
    return val;
}
```

That didn't end well. It worked at first, when no other functions were invoked afterwards (like `PrintList` or another `GetAtIndex`). But when I did try invoking other functions the program either crashed or ended up in an infinite loop. The fact that a similar issue didn't occur when I added a `free(temp)` line to the `PritList` function is even weirder...

What's actually going on here? Why is freeing a pointer that are just tracking my linked list members resulting in such weird behavior? Or maybe that issue stems from other parts of the program? And lastly, how and when should one free pointers to prevent memory leaks?

Comment: `GetAtIndex` does not "free a pointer ... just tracking ... linked list members".  It is freeing the node in the linked list itself (which is quite unexpected behavior from a function named `GetAtIndex`).  Consequently, the previous node in the linked list will have a `next` pointer that points to freed memory.  Every call to `free` should be matched to a corresponding allocation (e.g. `malloc`/`calloc`).

Comment: So that's why I'm not supposed to use free over there. Do you know why a similar error doesn't occur in the `PrintList` function? They're both very similar.

Comment: Note: `for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {  temp = temp->next; }` risks `temp` becoming `NULL` with a high index.

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monice that's correct, I'm planning to add a length check later on (and also a negative num check).

Comment: In `PrintList()` you're calling `free(NULL)` because it happens after the loop that stops when `temp == NULL`. That doesn't  do anything.

Comment: Ah that does make sense. Freeing memory in those 2 cases is both wrong and redundant then. Thanks for the answers guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`free(temp);` returns the memory that `temp` points to.  In this case it's a node which is problematic as it's still part of the linked list.  In `PrintList()` you read from memory that was fee'ed you have undefined behavior (UB). In `Erase()` you likely free one of the nodes again which is called a "double free" which is also UB.

0. Prefer `struct Node *` instead of `void *` for `next`.
1. `malloc()` returns NULL on failure.  If you don't check it will segfault when you try to deference that pointer.
2. `Node *NewNode(int value, Node *next)` heap allocates a node but `NewList()` is stack allocated.  It would be a more sensible design to be consist.  As `List` just tracks a single `head` pointer I would eliminate the type in favor for a variable `Node *lst`.  It does mean that when you want to change the caller's value of `*lst` then you need to pass in a `Node **lst`.
3. Prefer `for`-loops to `while`-loops for iteration.  They are built for it.
4. Arguments are passed by value in C, so your eliminate the temporary variables and just use the argument (`lst`).  See `Erase()`, `PrintList()`, `GetAtIndex()` (twice).
5. `Push()` is fine.  An alternative interface is to return the new root node:

   ```
   Node *Push(Node *lst, int val) {
     return NewNode(val, lst);
   }

   // ...

   lst = Push(lst, 6);
   ```

   The only difference between `Push()` and `NewNode()` is the order of arguments.  I would eliminate one of them and update callers.  Alternatively you could #define one in terms of other if you don't want the wrapper function.

   In the current implementation and the above consider using a temporary so you don't leak the tail of your list if `malloc()` fails.
6. `GetAtIndex()` will segfault if `index` is greater than number of elements.  The current interface doesn't have a way to return an error so I changed it return the status of operation either `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE` and value in a new out param `value`.  Consider using an `unsigned` type for indices otherwise you have to consider what happens what `GetAtIndex(lst, -17, &value)` means.  You want to use the same type for the index variable or just eliminate it as I did below.

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   typedef struct Node {
       int value;
       struct Node *next;
   } Node;

   Node *NewNode(int value, Node *next) {
       Node *new = malloc(sizeof *new);
       if(!new)
           return NULL;
       new->value = value;
       new->next = next;
       return new;
   }

   void Erase(Node *lst) {
       while (lst) {
           Node *next = lst->next;
           free(lst);
           lst = next;
       }
   }

   void PrintList(Node *lst) {
       printf("[ ");
       for(; lst; lst = lst->next) {
           printf("%d ", lst->value);
       }
       printf("]\n");
   }

   void Push(Node **lst, int val) {
       Node *new = NewNode(val, *lst);
       *lst = new;
   }

   int GetAtIndex(Node *lst, unsigned index, int *value) {
       for (; index && lst; index--, lst = lst->next);
       if(!lst)
           return EXIT_FAILURE;
       *value = lst->value;
       return EXIT_SUCCESS;
   }

   int main() {
       Node *lst = NULL;
       Push(&lst, 6);
       Push(&lst, 7);
       Push(&lst, 8);
       Push(&lst, 9);
       PrintList(lst);  // [ 9 8 7 6 ]
       PrintList(lst);

       unsigned index = 2;
       int value;
       if(GetAtIndex(lst, index, &value) == EXIT_SUCCESS)
           printf("lst[%u] = %d\n", index, value);
       else
           printf("out of bounds\n");

       PrintList(lst);
       Erase(lst);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for so much feedback! I agree with most of it and I'll definitely implement it, but I think I'll keep my `List` struct. If I wanted to make it heap allocated I could do that by changing my `NewList` function. And later I could store in it other data, like maybe the length of it, which would be more efficient than having to constantly calculate it over and over. One thing I really like is how you applied for loops, I haven't thought about using them in that way. Anyway, thank you once again!

Comment: @Imaginary If you need the length of the list it's a hint that you might be using the wrong data structure (array is the default choice).   I removed the `List` type to show you much you can strip away with no loss of functionality; if you need both `head` and `tail`  pointer (to do efficient queue and stack functionality) that would be a good use for it.

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks for the edit and I finally now know how to fix the indent issue in markdown! :-)

Comment: One more question. You mentioned that we need `**lst` when we want to modify the list, when we need to operate on the original object, rather than on a copy of it. If so, shouldn't we also pass `**lst` into `Erase` rather than just `*lst`?

Comment: When we need to modify the caller's variable then we need to pass in a pointer to the variable.  As the variable is `Node *lst` it means the argument would be `Node **lst`.  In this case the question do you care what the value of `lst` is in `main()` after `Erase()`?  If you want it to be NULL then yes, you would make the argument `Node **lst` and change the function to use `*lst` everywhere.  Usually, you don't care so it's ok that `lst` points to memory that was deallocated.  You just need to remember not to dereference it.  As it's the last call in `main()` that's seems reasonable.

Comment: With original code you never change the caller's `List` only the `head` variable.

Comment: I see. I'd personally use `Node **lst`, since I want `Erase` to both work as a cleanup function, and to turn any list into an empty list that could be re-used later. Thanks for further clarification, all that helped me a lot with understanding it properly.

Comment: You can reuse it either way.  The only relevant question for `Erase()` if you want it to update the value of caller's `Node *lst` to `NULL`.